# Is the code that I provide actually work with the AJAX call I'm trying to do to the Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out if the AJAX Call I have in my js file is actually working and sending the information back to the Servlet. I'm trying to figure out how to use the response that the servlet would give off to be used to display the Information thats provided by the user to appear.

**jTesting.js**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [50, 350],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val(
    "$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});

$(function() {

  var $user = $('#user');

  var $name = $('#name');
  var $phone = $('#phone');
  var $amount = $('#amount');


  $('#sendInfo').on(
    'click',
    function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var userInfo = {
        Name: $name.val(),
        Phone: $phone.val(),
        Amount: $amount.val()
      };

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'TestingServlet.do',
        timeout: 2000,
        data: userInfo,
        success: function() {
          var output = '<p>Name: ' + userInfo.Name + '</p> <br/>' + '<p>Phone: ' + userInfo.Phone + '</p> <br/>' + '<p>Amount: ' + userInfo.Amount + '</p><br/>';
          $user.html(output);

        },
        error: function() {
          alert("ERROR!");
        }
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery Testing</title>

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--- jQueryUI Library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jTesting.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form class="container form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">

    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>jQuery Testing</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Phone:</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" required />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Spending Range</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="slider-range"></div>
        <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="sendInfo">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <ul id="user"></ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**TestingServlet.java**

```
package com.jtesting.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@WebServlet("/TestingServlet")
public class TestingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String clientName = request.getParameter("Name");
        String clientPhone = request.getParameter("Phone");
        String spendingAmount = request.getParameter("Amount");

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add(clientName);
        list.add(clientPhone);
        list.add(spendingAmount);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put(response, list);

        System.out.println(clientName + ", " + clientPhone + ", " + spendingAmount);

        response.getWriter().write(obj.toJSONString());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestingServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jtesting.servlet.TestingServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestingServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/TestingServlet.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I Dont know completely if my code is actually doing whats its supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the response from your servlet on your front end, change your Javascript to:

```
success: function(response) {
    // response variable is the output your servlet generated, so eg:
    // console.log(response) if it is text/html
    // console.dir(response) if it is json
    // $('div.result').html(response.message) for example
    // ...
}
```

If your servlet returns JSON, add dataType to your $.ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
});
```

To check if your AJAX call is working, open your browser's developer tools and check the network activity tab.  You should see the http request, and be able to see what data was sent, and the servlet response.

Comment: Network Tab is showing Servlet is being called and responding back with Information. Lets say I wanted to display the information back to the same page without refreshing. .html(...) or .appendTo(...) would work?

Comment: Yes, exactly as I described in the code above: `$('div.result').html(response.message) for example`

Comment: Thanks, Lets say if I wanted to split the results and have them displayed on a table, How would that be done/

Comment: That's really another question, and depends on what format your result is in.

Comment: If my answer helped would you mind accepting?  Thanks.